# How to edit using ObjectContext for jqGrid purpose or any task

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

Since i get through all the jqGrid CRUD tutorial basically most of it cover on DBcontext approach instead of using ObjectContext.  The code that i take is from the tutorial given inside this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/performing-crud-operation-using-jqgrid-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

```
public string Edit(StudentMaster Model)  
{  
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();  
string msg;  
try  
{  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {  
        db.Entry(Model).State = EntityState.Modified;  
        db.SaveChanges();  
        msg = "Saved Successfully";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        msg = "Validation data not successfully";  
    }  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
    msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;  
}  
return msg;  
}
```

Is there any solution to change this to ObjectContext approach?
my objectcontext is

```
ECONSOVEntities1 db = new ECONSOVEntities1();
```

Basically the part i need to change is this part only if im not mistaken.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {  
        db.Entry(Model).State = EntityState.Modified;  
        db.SaveChanges();  
        msg = "Saved Successfully";  
    }
```

If there any link that same question as me, can include it as well so i can easily refer there, thank you.

Comment: You should realize that `ObjectContext` died a long time ago, as it was replaced by `DbContext` on EF5 (IIRC). You also should update to EF6 in order to get the latest performance/security improvements as well as of course new features.

Answer (score -1):

I guess i already got the answer lol...
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

```
using (SchoolDBContext newCtx = new SchoolDBContext())
{
    newCtx.Students.Attach(stud);
    newCtx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(stud, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);        
    newCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```